# Зачем нужны Lambda-функции?

Tags: python, lambda

Изучая `Python`, наткнулся на `lambda`-функции. Но нигде я пока не нашел примера, где они *действительно* нужны - только элементарные примеры вида `print(lambda x, y: x**2 + y**2)`, где вполне можно убрать функциональную обертку. Для чего они действительно нужны и полезны?

Comment: `print(lambda: ...)` печатает саму функцию (объект), что практически всегда бесполезно.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Они не могут быть 100% *нужны*, то есть без операций сложений написать программу нельзя, без лямбда-функций - можно, но с ними короче и удобней. Например, нужно напечатать словарь в порядке убывания суммы каждого значения:

```
bigrams = {"AB": [10, 11, 12], "BC": [5, -5, 8], "CD": [105, 1, 0], 
           "DE": [6, 6], "EF": [15, 20, 15], "FG": [22, 11, 32], 
           "GH": [20, 20, 20]}
sorter = sorted(bigrams, key=lambda key: sum(bigrams[key]), reverse=True)

for key in sorter:
    print(key, bigrams[key])
```

Иначе нужно написать функцию:

```
from functools import partial

def sort_func(key, dict):
    return sum(dict[key])

bigrams = {"AB": [10, 11, 12], "BC": [5, -5, 8], "CD": [105, 1, 0], 
           "DE": [6, 6], "EF": [15, 20, 15], "FG": [22, 11, 32], 
           "GH": [20, 20, 20]}
partial_sort = partial(sort_func, dict=bigrams)
sorter = sorted(bigrams.keys(), key=partial_sort, reverse=True)

for key in sorter:
    print(key, bigrams[key])
```

Результат одинаков, но с лямбдой короче, не нужно искать глазами `sort_func` - сразу ясно, как именно сортируется коллекция. В стандартной библиотеке полно функций, которые принимают другие функции: `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, `sorted`, `any`, `all`

Можно написать замыкание:

```
def addition(x):
    return lambda y: x + y
add_to_ten = addition(10)
print(add_to_ten(8))
print(add_to_ten(6))
```

По идее, лямбда функции абсолютно то же самое, что и обычные функции, но без имени:

```
def func(x):
    func = lambda x: x + 1
    return 100

import dis
print(dis.dis(func))
```

показывает, что действительно создается новая функция, без обмана.

Answer (score 8):

`lambda` создаёт анонимные функции в Питоне. Основные отличия от `def f()` это отсутствие имени и ограничение на тело функции до одного выражения.
Фактически создаваемые объекты c помощью `lambda` выражения или `def` конструкции могут быть одинаковыми:

```
>>> type(lambda: None)
<class 'function'>
>>> def f(): return None
... 
>>> type(f)
<class 'function'>
```

`lambda` часто используется для callback в GUI и сетевых библиотеках (асинхронный код), например:

```
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop()) # twisted
signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, lambda signum, frame: None) # enable SIGCHLD
root.bind("<Escape>", lambda _: root.destroy())  # exit on Esc
root.bind('<Left>', app.prev_image)
# change font that widgets with 'TButton' style use
root.after(3000, lambda: ttk.Style().configure('TButton', font=MyFont)) # in 3 secs
```

`lambda` можно использовать в любом месте, где ожидается функция:

```
intervals.sort(key=lambda x: (x.end, (x.end - x.start)))
problem.addConstraint(lambda a,b: b+1 == a, ["green", "yellow"])
def longest_alphabetical_substring(text, rank=lambda char: char): ...
```

или:

```
>>> sorted([(1,-1), (2,-2)]) 
[(1, -1), (2, -2)]
>>> sorted([(1,-1), (2,-2)], key=lambda (a, b): (b, a)) 
[(2, -2), (1, -1)]
```

Этот Python 2 код сортирует пары сначала по `b`, потом по `a` в отличии сортировки для кортежей по умолчанию.

Часто `lambda` используется без нужды, например чтобы отсортировать файлы по времени последней модификации в Питоне:

```
#XXX DO NOT DO IT
files.sort(key=lambda path: os.path.getmtime(path)) # не делайте этого
```

Вместо этого следует передать функцию прямо:

```
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Если вам приходится использовать `lambda` в выражениях с `filter()`, `map()`, то следует переписать их, используя генераторы списков, что может сделать код одновременно более читаемым и эффективным, например, вместо:

```
strings = list(map(lambda b: b.decode('utf-8').replace(os.linesep, '\n'),
                   bytestrings))
```

лучше написать:

```
strings = [b.decode('utf-8').replace(os.linesep, '\n') for b in bytestrings]
```

В некоторых случаях, код с `lambda` может быть менее ясен для новичков, например:

```
duplicate = reduce(lambda acc, (i, x): acc ^ i ^ x, enumerate(arr), 0)

def lcm(*args):
    """Least common multiple."""
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a * b // gcd(a, b), args)
```

(что лучше переписать, используя явный цикл). Или наоборот более ясен:

```
L.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
# vs: L.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))
for chunk in iter(lambda: file.read(1 << 13), b'')
# vs: for chunk in iter(functools.partial(file.read, 1 << 13), b'')
```

Связанные вопросы:

- [Multiline Lambda in Python: Why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1233448/4279)
- [Why are Python lambdas useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/890128/4279)
- [Useful code which uses reduce() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15995/4279)

Answer (score 3):

`lambda` функции можно вставлять как параметры функции,например в встроенную функцию `sorted в key=` можно задать ламбду.

Answer (score 3):

Важно разделять лямбды и замыкания.

1. Замыкания - нужны, очень полезны. Применимы в функциональной парадигме программирования, в том числе в функциях обратного вызова (callback), функциях высшего порядка (HOF).
   Считаю замыкания полезным средством инкапсуляции (связывания) кода и данных, альтернативой инкапсуляции в ООП.
2. Лямбда-выражения на Python - конструкторы простых безымянных однострочных функций. Бывают полезны (или нет). Вы можете использовать их для создания замыканий там, где не хотите использовать для создания замыкания именованную функцию. Например, в однострочниках.

Безымянные функции - короче. Именованные функции удобней для отладки и повторного использования.

Лямбды не являются необходимыми ни для функциональной парадигмы, ни для программирования в целом. Представляют собой синтаксический сахар для любителей писать скрипты коротко и быстро. Без любого синтаксического сахара всегда можно обойтись. Вопрос - нужно ли.

Простой и понятный пример на основе кода и пояснения Xyanight, и кода python-scripts.com/lambda . Этот вариант не требует установки PIL, он короче, яснее, не отвлекает внимания от сути примера, работает на Python 2 и 3.

"Допустим, вы создаете в цикле сто кнопок в вашем UI. И каждая такая кнопка вызывает одну и ту же функцию, но с разными параметрами."

```
import tkinter as tk  # Tkinter - Python2, tkinter - Python3

class App:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        frame = tk.Frame(parent)
        frame.pack()
        for i in range(7):
            tk.Button(
                frame,
                text=str(i),
                command=lambda numButton=i: self.printNum(numButton)
            ).pack(side=tk.LEFT)           
        tk.Button(frame, text="Cancel circle", fg="red", command=frame.quit).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def printNum(self, num):
        print("Вы нажали кнопку: %s" % num)

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

В данном коде я связываю данные (номер кнопки) и код (экземплярный метод printNum) в замыкание, с помощью lambda, для отложенного (callback) вызова этой функции с инкапсулированными внутрь замыкания данными (у каждой Button ее параметр command помнит и код печати, и номер кнопки для печати). Код с lambda короче и ясней, чем при использовании именованной функции (созданной с помощью def, а не lambda) в качестве замыкания.

Это мой первый пост на Stackoverflow. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Попробую еще проще. Практичемкий пример.

Допустим, вы создаете в цикле сто кнопок в вашем UI. И каждая такая кнопка вызывает одну  и ту же функцию, но с разными параметрами.

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class UserUI(tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self, setting_image=None, help_image=None):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.body = tkinter.Canvas(self.root, width=250, height=60)
        self.body.pack()

        self.setting_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(setting_image))
        self.help_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(help_image))

        pos = 5
        for number_button in range(7):
            pos += 40
            self.button = tkinter.Button(
                self.body, width=30, height=20, image=self.setting_image,
                command=lambda number_button=number_button: self.set(number_button))

            self.button.pack()
            self.body.create_window((pos, 30), anchor="nw", window=self.button)

    def show(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def set(self, number_button):
        print("Press button {}".format(number_button))


user_ui = UserUI("icon.png", "icon.png")
user_ui.show()
```

**Результат:**

```
>>> Press button 0
>>> Press button 1
>>> Press button 2
>>> Press button 3
>>> Press button 4
```

Теперь при нажатии любой из ста ваших кнопок будут выведены разные параметры.
А теперь попробуйте сделать то же самое без lambda выражений...

Comment: Да, пардон, правильно lambda number_button=number_button: callback(number_button)))

Comment: Нет, не сломается!

Comment: Изменил ответ - проверьте, чтобы глаза не резало! Я человеку пример использования привел, а вы к параметрам цепляетесь :))))

Comment: А ты понимаешь, что tkinter здесь ни при чем?! А приведен просто, как пример. Все, свободен, мальчик!