# Как удалить повторы в списке списков по второму элементу?

Tags: python, list

У меня есть список списков. Например:

```
my_list=[['ewew','bbb','fff'],['123','bbb','fff'],['333','bbb','wff']]
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в списке были уникальные по второму элементу подсписка?
Лучше, конечно, через lambda или ещё что-то скоростное.

Comment: Почему вы считаете использование lambda "скоростным" решением?

Comment: Потому что это та же функция, но занимает меньше места .

Comment: @Demian, [Зачем нужны lambda-функции](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534344/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-lambda-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Чтобы удалить повторы, отредактируйте вопрос

Comment: Какие ещё подписки? В вашем вопросе фигурирует только список списков.

Comment: Авто-правка постаралась, 2-ой элемент подсписка.

Answer (score 2):

`unique_list = [l for l in {i[1]: i for i in my_list}.values()]`

Наверняка есть и более изящные решения.

Comment: Спс, хотелось бы увидеть что-нибудь интересненькое.

Comment: filter(lambda i, s=set(): not (i[1] in s or s.add(i[1])), my_list)

Comment: можно: `unique_lists = list({lst[1]: lst for lst in list_of_lists}.values())`