# Как поочередно изменить регистр символов с нижнего в верхний и наоборот?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

```
def to_weird_case(string):
    num = 0
    new_word = []
    for i in string:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num += 1
            i.upper()
            new_word.append(i)
        else:
            num += 1
            i.lower()
            new_word.append(i)
    print(new_word)

to_weird_case('Test for test')
```

Столкнулся с заданием, изменить регистр символов, чтобы с данной строки:

```
Test for test
```

получилось:

```
TeSt FoR tEsT
```

Функции `upper()` и `lower()` не изменяют регистр. В чем подвох? Изменил результат который должен получить, извините, не доглядел, нужно сделать первый символ uppercase, второй lowcase и т.д по очереди.

```
def to_weird_case(string):
    num = 0
    new_word = []
    for i in string:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num += 1
            new_word.append(i.upper())
        else:
            num += 1
            new_word.append(i.lower())
    print(''.join(new_word))
```

С вашей помощью код работает, спасибо!
Есть задание что бы реализовать слова с пробелами

```
to_weird_case('Weird string case') # => returns 'WeIrD StRiNg CaSe'
```

Могу разбить строку примерно так:

```
s = 'Weird string case' 
l = s.split()
s1 = ''
for i in l:
    s1 += i + ' '
print(s1)
```

И потом на каждое слово применять предыдущий код, но ясно, что это не есть правильное решение.

Подскажите, как реализовать?

Comment: `i.lower()` и `i.upper()` не изменяют исходную строку, а возвращают измененную строку. В вашем коде нужно сделать просто `new_word.append(i.lower())` и `new_word.append(i.upper())`. Ну еще потом при выводе `new_word` превратить из списка в строку: `''.join(new_word)`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Теперь я понял в чем ошибка)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Новая версия, которая разбивает строку на слова:**

пошагово - функция занимающаяся изменением регистра в слове:

```
def to_weird_case2(sss):
    return ''.join([c.upper() if i % 2 == 0
                    else c.lower()
                    for i,c in enumerate(sss)])
```

применение данной функции с использованием "list comprehension":

```
sss = 'Weird string case'
' '.join([to_weird_case2(w) for w in sss.split()])
```

Тест:

```
In [76]: ' '.join([to_weird_case2(w) for w in sss.split()])
Out[76]: 'WeIrD StRiNg CaSe'
```

Монолитная функция, которая делает сразу все (универсальнее, конечно иметь маленькие функции-строительные-блоки, каждая из которых, занимается своей одной задачей)

```
def to_weird_case(sss):
    return ' '.join([
                ''.join([
                        c.upper() if i % 2 == 0
                        else c.lower()
                        for i,c in enumerate(s)
                ])
                for s in sss.split()
           ])
```

Тест:

```
In [70]: to_weird_case('Weird string case')
Out[70]: 'WeIrD StRiNg CaSe'
```

**Старая версия:**

если вам надо поменять местами верхний и нижний регистры:

```
In [11]: s
Out[11]: 'Test for test'

In [12]: new = ''.join([x.lower() if x.isupper() else x.upper() for x in s])

In [13]: new
Out[13]: 'tEST FOR TEST'
```

если вы хотите преобразовать к верхнему регистру все символы с четными индексами и к нижнему с нечетными:

```
In [37]: new = ''.join([c.upper() if i % 2 == 0 else c.lower() for i,c in enumerate(s)])

In [38]: new
Out[38]: 'TeSt fOr tEsT'
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли!

Comment: Предпочтительно только пошаговый вариант показывать для примера вместо монолитной функции. Вот ещё вариант: `words = text.split(); print(*map(interleave_case, words))`, где `interleave_case = lambda s: ''.join(map(''.join, zip_longest(s[::2].upper(), s[1::2].lower(), fillvalue='')))`

Comment: @jfs, спасибо за дельный комментарий! Мне кажется вам стоит оформить это решение в виде отдельного ответа, т.к. он, похоже, значительно лучше моего. У меня вчера была похожая идея (использовать `s[::2].upper()`, `s[1::2].lower()` с `zip()` и `map()`), но у меня так и не получилось заставить правильно работать `zip()` для строк с нечетной длиной - о `zip_longest()` я совсем забыл...

Comment: Для отдельного ответа, код из моего комментария слишком сложен для вероятных читателей данного вопроса (новичков как в Питоне так и в программировании). Если есть желание, то добавьте это решение с объяснением в ваш ответ.

Comment: @jfs, мне кажется код и тем более пояснение к нему стоит делать автору, иначе может получиться эффект "испорченного телефона". По поводу полезности я не совсем согласен - учиться никогда  (и никому) не поздно... :)

Comment: Будет отлично если вы напишите свою реализацию, я пока с lambda & map знаком поверхностно, но рано или поздно вернусь к данному вопросу и пригодится однозначно. К тому же вы можете помочь и более опытным, приветствую ваше решение отдельным ответом)

Comment: @jfs, согласен с maximus - это может пригодится и опытным и новичкам

Comment: Для опытных программистов, код без пояснений  ясен (задача простая—если добавить `from itertools import zip_longest`, то 3 строчки это полный код). В противном случае одного ответа может быть мало (в зависимости от того что не ясно, например нужно ли объяснять что функции могут принимать другие функции в виде параметров или [чем lambda от def-функций отличается](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/534378/23044). Если вы думаете что данный код легко неправильно интерпретировать, то тем больше оснований другому человеку код объяснять—задача любого кода передать намерение одного программиста другому.

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой способ (более понятный, легко изменяемый):

```
string = "Test for test"
new_string = ""
for i in string:
    if i.isupper():
        new_string += i.lower()
    else:
        new_string += i.upper()
```

Дополнительно о методах string объекта [здесь.](http://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
def camel(st):

    data = iter(st)
    return ''.join([x.upper() + y.lower() for x, y in zip(data, data)])

print(camel('metallica'))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]