# Telebot handlers. Ряд вопросов по func=lambda и к нему прилежащих

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
```

Из этого:

1. Что такое `lambda`? Можно ли в хенделере заменить лямбду на что-то
   другое? Если да, то на что?
2. Что такое m и почему после него двоеточие? Я видел, что вместо `m`
   может быть `message` или `call`. Как значение `m` \ `message` \ `call` влияют на
   код написанный под хедлером?
3. `True`. Вместо `True`, как я понимаю, может стоять условие, которое
   связанно с тем, что стоит до двоеточия, и, если это значение True,
   то будет активирован хендлер, верно?? Например,
   `@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.reply_to_message
   is None, content_types=['text'])` будет выполняться, когда сообщение
   не было reply'ем.
4. Может ли `func=` содержать условие, которое вообще не относится к telebot? Если да, то покажите, пожалуйста, простой пример

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с этими вопросами. Пишу ботов 6 мес, да и вообще изучаю Python столько же, а этого момента с лямбдой никак понять не могу.

Comment: Откройте учебник Питона да посмотрите что такое лямбда. Это будет быстрее чем ждать пока тут кто-нибудь перескажет вам главу из учебника.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/534344/255866

Comment: @Twiss Спасибо! Просто я не додумался загуглять Лямбду отдельно от телебота

Answer (score 0):

То, что нашел в документации:
Он использует лямбда-функцию для проверки сообщения. Если лямбда возвращает True, сообщение обрабатывается декорированной функцией. Поскольку мы хотим, чтобы все сообщения обрабатывались этой функцией, мы просто всегда возвращаем True.