# Как через bind в модуле tkinter передавать свои переменные?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, bind

Исходник:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Canvas

root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root,width=100,height=100)
c.pack()

def opt(event):
    print(url1)

url1 = "vk.com"
url2 = "ok.ru"

but1 = Button(text="Vk")
but1.bind(sequence="<Button-3>",func=opt)
but1.pack()

but2 = Button(text="Ok")
but2.bind(sequence="<Button-3>",func=opt)
but2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на кнопку vk передавался `url1 = "vk.com"`  функции и он пишет `"vk.com"`.

А если нажать на ok то url передается `url2 = "ok.ru"`  и пишет `"ok.ru"`

Нажимать нужно именно `"<Button-3>"`

Comment: в сторону: обычно `command` параметр используется, чтобы действие на нажатие кнопки повесить¶ Можно своё событие сгенерировать и передать с ним данные, которые затем в обработчике, зарегистрированном  bind получить, [пример (внешняя команда генерирует строчки, GUI их показывает)](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288#file-kill-process-py-L31)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте  [`lambda`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534344/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-lambda-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/797287#797287)

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Canvas


def opt(items):
    print(items)


root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
c.pack()

url1 = "vk.com"
url2 = "ok.ru"

but1 = Button(text="Vk")
but1.bind(sequence="<Button-3>", func=lambda event: opt(url1))
but1.pack()

but2 = Button(text="Ok")
but2.bind(sequence="<Button-3>", func=lambda event: opt(url2))
but2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое и в тот и в этот раз!)