# Обновление Label при нажатии на кнопку tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

задача создать оконное приложение в python 3, в котором есть три кнопки, расположенные в одном ряду, а ниже поле label  в котором будет выводиться информация при нажатии на кнопку, какая кнопка нажата.

помогите с def для click разобраться

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.title('"HOME WORK"')
dx = [1, 2, 3]
def click_button():
    root.label("Button {}".format(dx))



button = Button( text = "button 1", command = click_button)
button1 = Button( text = "button 2", command = click_button)
button2 = Button( text = "button 3", command = click_button)

label = Label( text = "Position 1 ", bg = "yellow", fg = "red", width = 10, height = 5)

label.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

button.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
button1.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
button2.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

button.bind(root,"button 1", click_button)
label.bind(root,"button 1", click_button)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю к чему вообще относится строчка `root.label("Button {}".format(dx))` потому что ее смысле вообще не понятен. Так же не вижу смысла в использовании списка который бы передавал в функции какой то параметр(без понятия что он должен передавать).
Для того чтобы изменить текст в `label` используйте функцию
`.config(text="")`
или
[`label["text"] = ""`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821217/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-label-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-tkinter/821224?noredirect=1#comment1306972_821224)
А для того чтобы в `label` обновлять значения номера нажатой кнопки вы можете просто передавать значение в функцию и обновлять `label` внутри функции.
[Почему используется `lambda:` в `command`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775139/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0/775146#775146)
[Как такие же манипуляции выполнять с `bind`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797266/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-bind-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5-tkinter-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5/797269#797269)

Исправленный код:

```
from tkinter import *


def click_button(text):
    label.config(text="Button {}".format(text))


root = Tk()
root.title('"HOME WORK"')

button = Button(text="button 1", command=lambda: click_button(1)).grid(row=2, column=1)
button1 = Button(text="button 2", command=lambda: click_button(2)).grid(row=2, column=2)
button2 = Button(text="button 3", command=lambda: click_button(3)).grid(row=2, column=3)

label = Label(text="Position 1 ", bg="yellow", fg="red", width=10, height=5)

label.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так, наверное, проще выглядеть будет: `label['text'] = "Button {}".format(text))` ? Вот странно что нельзя просто `label.text = `

Comment: @gil9red ну это не `PyQt`) там более перспективнее функционал

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was really helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

Обобщение, которое работает для произвольного `NBUTTONS` количества кнопок:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label

NBUTTONS = 3
root = Tk()
label = Label(text="no button pressed")
label.grid(row=1, columnspan=NBUTTONS)
for i in range(NBUTTONS):
    t = f"button {i+1}"
    b = Button(text=t, command=lambda t=t: label.configure(text=t))
    b.grid(row=0, column=i)
root.mainloop()
```